# monitor.isOver({shallow:true}) is not returning the correct value from react-dnd useDrop hook in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have some draggable elements in Sidebar component from there I am dragging element and before dropping them into the workspace area i want to know if I am dropping the element on the workspace or on its children. I read the docs of react-dnd and came to know if I use `monitor.isOver({shallow: true})` then it will return true if I am hovering over on the element itself and false if on children. But it returning true on both cases. The code snippet below is a sample code but it replicate my problem. Any suggestion would be very helpful for me.
*Please do not give any suggestion from AI as i already used AI's help and get no result *

```
export default function TestC() {
const dropRef = useRef(null);


const hRef = useRef(null);
  const [{ isOver, canDrop }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: ["element", "component"],
    hover: (item, monitor) => {
      let a = monitor.isOver({ shallow: true });
      console.log(a);
    },
    drop: (item, monitor) => {},
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: monitor.isOver({ shallow: true }),
      canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
    }),
  }));
  drop(dropRef);
return (
        <div className="flex justify-around">
          <Sidebar />
          <div className="w-[600px] h-[2000px] border-2 border-dashed border-amber-500">
            <div
              id="a"
              data-wb-id="workspace"
              ref={dropRef}
              role={`Dustbin`}
              className={`w-full h-full`}
              style={{
                backgroundColor: isOver ? "green" : "gray",
                overflow: "auto",
              }}
            >
              <h1 id="b" ref={hRef} className=" border-2 border-orange-400 mb-3">
                Test1
              </h1>
              <p id="c" className="">
                Test2
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```